# parse json object That stringify Twice

Tags: javascript, json

How can i parse some object that stringify twice?

Most of the time in my code it is not problem but some times it stringify twice, and I can not trace the code to find my problem.

My JSON object something like this:

```
""[{\"name\":\"trane\",\"price\":\"150000\",\"order\":\"\",\"sale\":\"\",\"printedPic\":\"\",\"remainingPic\":\"\",\"locationEncome\":\"\"}]""
```

Comment: I'd answer "apply `JSON.parse` twice" ... but obviously, the best thing you can do is find where `stringify` is applied twice

Comment: not work i try it tanx any way

Answer (score 16):

It's definitely best to figure out where and why it's stringifying twice, but you can just parse twice if you have to.

`JSON.parse(JSON.parse("JSON STRING HERE"))`

**Edit**

Potentially you're stringifying an already stringified object, this could help you figure out what is going wrong.

Add this function to your code and then replace your `JSON.stringify` calls to `JSON.stringifyIfObject` calls. Just use this as a means of debugging though, I wouldn't put this into production.

```
JSON.stringifyIfObject = function stringifyIfObject(obj){
    if(typeof obj == "object")
        return JSON.stringify(obj);
    else{
        alert("found already stringified object")
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: tanx but every time i trace to debug it its not problem and every thing is perfect and i can not parse it becuse its not now it as object to parse

Comment: @Pooria.Shariatzadeh  I just added an edit that might help your debugging

Comment: it is helpful but my problem is that I don't no when my program is buged I mean I try over 30 time to debug it but every time its work without problem but install program on server has  this problem just tow time in over 60 record that saved in db  so I don't now what is the problem or where  I most look

Answer (score 0):

This post is a little bit old but I had the same problem today and it was caused by a third party library.

Javascript library Prototype.js applies JSON.stringify() twice when it is used in version 1.6.x (it seems that this bug was removed in version 1.7)

The following code :

```
var test = ["banana"];
JSON.stringify(test);
```

will give you the following result :

```
""[\"banana\"]""
```

instead of (normally expected) :

```
"["banana"]"
```

Here is my source :
https://github.com/krinkle/jquery-json/issues/35

If that happens to you, the best option is to upgrade that library if you can.